# I want to set the topic name of a spring cloud stream kafka on runtime. How can I do it?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am using the following configurations to define the topic name

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: topicA
```

I want to know how can we do this programmatically at runtime so that we don't have to define it here. I am using Spring Kafka Binders. TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `StreamBridge` and send to any topic. If it doesn't exist the binder will provision it for you - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

Comment: In the example we have streamBridge.send("myBinidng", body);     StreamBridge sends data to the "myBinidng" binding. But I want to do a discovery on the topicName & then send the data to that that particular topic. Is there a way how we can specify the destination name during runtime programmatically & not using the yml configs?

Comment: You can simply replace "myBinding" with whatever topic name that the discovery mechanism found, for ex: `streamBridge.send("from-discovery-1-topic", data)`, `streamBridge.send("from-discovery-2-topic" data)` so on and so forth. In this case, the binding name is not coming from config, but the binding becomes the first argument for the send method. By default, the binding name in this case becomes the topic name.